# How to show each item in a PureScript List

Tags: purescript

Is there like a foreach method in purescript lists? the foreach method takes each item of the list and returns a unit.

its a good method to print each item of a list.

Edit: I am trying the traverse method as suggested below but I am getting an error

```
import Data.Traversable (traverse)
removeDuplicate :: AddressBook -> AddressBook 
removeDuplicate = nubBy (\a b -> a.firstName == b.firstName && a.lastName == b.lastName)    
let dedup = removeDuplicate addressBook  
traverse (\a -> log (showEntry a)) dedup

Compiling Main
Error found:
in module Main
at src/Main.purs line 73, column 3 - line 73, column 49

  Could not match type

    List Unit

  with type

    Unit


while trying to match type Eff
                             ( console :: CONSOLE
                             | t1
                             )
                             t2
  with type Eff
              ( console :: CONSOLE
              | e0
              )
              Unit
while checking that expression (discard (logShow ((...) addressBook))) (\__unused ->
                                                                          (discard (...)) (\__unused ->
                                                                                             ...
                                                                                          )
                                                                       )
  has type Eff
             ( console :: CONSOLE
             | e0
             )
             Unit
in value declaration main

where e0 is a rigid type variable
        bound at line 63, column 8 - line 78, column 38
      t2 is an unknown type
      t1 is an unknown type

See https://github.com/purescript/documentation/blob/master/errors/TypesDoNotUnify.md for more information,
or to contribute content related to this error.
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`for_`](https://pursuit.purescript.org/search?q=for_) which allows you to perform an "applicative action" on every item of a `Foldable` (`List` and `Array` have `Foldable` instances) and ignores this action result:

```hs
module Main where

import Control.Monad.Eff.Console (logShow)
import Data.Foldable (for_)
import Prelude

main = do
  -- I'm using an Array here for simplicity, but the same goes for List
  let l = [1, 2, 3, 4]

  for_ l \i → logShow i
```

`List` has also `Show` instance ([second on the instances list](https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-lists/4.8.0/docs/Data.List.Lazy.Types#t:List)) (and Array too -
 [last on the instances list](https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-prelude/3.1.0/docs/Data.Show#t:Show)) so you can print them using `logShow` directly if they contain values of type which has `Show` instance.

Answer (score 6):

Sure, it exists. It's called [`map`](https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-prelude/3.1.0/docs/Data.Functor#v:map). You can certainly use it to apply a function `a -> unit` to every element of an array:

```
arr = [1, 2, 3]
map (\a -> unit) arr
```

However, the second part of your post - "*its a good method to print each item of a list*" - is not true. A function that takes an item and returns a unit certainly cannot print anything. PureScript is a pure language, pure functions cannot have effects in them.

To print something, you need a function that returns an `Eff` or an `Aff`, such as [`log`](https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-console/3.0.0/docs/Control.Monad.Eff.Console#v:log). To apply such function over an array (or another container), use [`traverse`](https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-foldable-traversable/3.4.0/docs/Data.Traversable#v:traverse):

```
arr = [1, 2, 3]
traverse (\a -> log $ show a) arr
```

`traverse` will apply the function to each element and execute the resulting effect, in order of elements.

Comment: I am getting an error on traverse. My code is in my question.

Comment: `traverse` proposed by Fyodor works fine:

http://try.purescript.org/?session=ba5b2132-2833-aa33-793d-3b3b5bd6cfc5&backend=core&gist=92b681d0d3e926f14afa0624c4b7163c

;-)

Comment: @paluh the OP tried to use `traverse` as return value of `main`, and got an error, because the return type didn't match.

Comment: @FyodorSoikin Ok, but it is not entirely clear from the above error snippet. Anyways I just wanted to point out that `traverse` works fine ;-)

Comment: @paluh oh, I agree it works fine. I was just explaining why the OP didn't accept it.